# Adding a node with attribute in a NetworkX graph

Tags: python, networkx

The [networkx tutorial](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#nodes) hints the possibility of adding a node with attributes.

> You can also add nodes along with node attributes if your container yields 2-tuples of the form `(node, node_attribute_dict)`

When I try it with the `add_node` method, I get a TypeError:

```py
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(('person1', {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 40}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/windows/Users/godidier/Projects/semlab/research/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 506, in add_node
    if node_for_adding not in self._node:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

What am I missing ? or is adding nodes with attributes only possible with the `add_nodes_from` method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right method in your case would be `G.add_nodes_from`

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_nodes_from([('person1', {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 40})])
>>> G.nodes['person1']
{'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 40}
```

or also directly using `add_node`:

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node('person1', name='John Doe', age=40)
>>> G.nodes['person1']
{'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 40}
```